# How do update maven dependencies in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, pom.xml, build-automation

I have a few jobs in Jenkins - Jobs A,B and C.

A - is the version file. In the pom.xml there are versions for all the files.

B & C - other projects. In jenkins they are set up as a dependency for A. So after A is built B and C will be built.

```
**A set up**
<version>2023Sep.0<version>
<properties>
   <B>1.1.0</B>
   <c>1.2.0</C>
 </properties> 




**B and C set up**
<version>2023Sep.0</version>
```

All the projects have a pom.xml file. Now I need to update files. First i want to update project A . The version has change for 'A' and the version for 'B' has changed.

```
**'A' set up**
<version>2023Oct.0<version>
<properties>
   <B>1.2.0</B>
   <c>1.2.0</C>
 </properties>
```

Since 'B' was changed 'B's version in its pom.xml needs to change. It needs to become
`<version>2023Oct.0</version>`

Is there a way to do this through Jenkins. These are freestyle jobs its not a pipeline. I could do it through code but I was hoping there would be an easier way through Jenkins.

Can this happen??

Optional

Here would be the perfect way for this to work.

1. project A pom file is updated and Jenkins job is enabled.
2. other projects pom.xml files are updated
3. PR are opened to update those pom files
4. once PR has enough approvals Jenkins automatically enables jobs for those projects and builds them.